# Create pagination from arrays

Tags: php, html, css

I have this carousel which the data inside is queried from database and has been sorted by month. I set for every page only to have 3 carousel which I named it according to months.

So let say I have 12 rows of data in database and 4 of them is for January, another 4 for February, 2 for March, and 2 for April so there are 4 carousel. So in my page only 3 latest carousel will be displayed first and then user can select next page to see the remaining carousel.

```
function printCard($keys,$month,$count){       
    echo "<h3 class='title' style='width: fit-content; margin-top: 2%; margin-left: 30px;'>" . $month . " News</h3>";
        echo "<div id='$month' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>";
            echo "<div class='carousel-inner'>";
                $item = count($keys);
                    foreach($keys as $row){  
                        if($count == 0){
                            echo "<div class='carousel-item active'>";
                            echo "<div class='container'>";
                            echo "<div class='row'>";
                        }
                        else if($count%4==0){
                            echo "<div class='carousel-item'>";
                            echo "<div class='container'>";
                            echo "<div class='row'>";
                        }
                        // if($row['month']=="December"){
                    echo "<div class='col-md-3'>";
                    echo "<div class='card mb-4 box-shadow'>";
                    echo "<a href='".$row['media_path']."' target='_blank'>";
                    echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='".$row['thumb_nail']."' alt='Card image cap'>";
                    echo "<div class='card-img-overlay'>";
                     echo "</div>";
                    echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                   echo "<h5 class='card-title' style='width: fit-content; padding: 3px; position: absolute; right: 4%; top: 3%;'>". $row['source_news'] ."</h5>";
                    echo "<p class='card-text'>". $row['title'] ."</p>";
                    echo "<div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>";
                    echo "<small class='text-muted'>". $row['day_news'] ." ".$row['month_news']." ".$row['year_news']."</small>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    $count++;
                        // }
                    if($count%4!=0){
                        if($count!=$item){
                        // if($row['month']=="December"){
                        continue;}
                    }
                    
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                                                                  
                    }
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "<a class='carousel-control-prev' href='#$month' role='button' data-slide='prev'>";
                    echo "<span class='carousel-control-prev-icon' aria-hidden='true'></span>";
                    echo "<span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>";
                    echo "</a>";
                echo "<a class='carousel-control-next' href='#$month' role='button' data-slide='next'>";
                    echo "<span class='carousel-control-next-icon' aria-hidden='true'></span>";
                    echo "<span class='sr-only'>Next</span>";
                    echo "</a>";
                echo "</div>";
    }
```

I created a function to display the carousel and this is how I call the function

```
if(!empty($keysDec)){
                if($page==1){
                printCard($keysDec,$monthDec,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysNov)){
                if($page==1){
                printCard($keysNov,$monthNov,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysOct)){
                if($page==1){
                printCard($keysOct,$monthOct,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysSep)){
                if($page==2){
                    if($printRange<=3){printCard($keysSep,$monthSep,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;}
                    else{;}
                }
                else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3){
                printCard($keysSep,$monthSep,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysAug)){
                if($page==2){
                    if($printRange<=3){printCard($keysAug,$monthAug,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;}
                    else{;}
                }
                else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3){
                printCard($keysAug,$monthAug,$count);
                $contentPrint++; }
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysJul)){
                if($page==2){
                    if($printRange>=3){;}
                    else{printCard($keysJul,$monthJul,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;}
                }
                else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange>=3){
                printCard($keysJul,$monthJul,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysJun)){
                if($page==3){
                    if($printRange<=4){printCard($keysJun,$monthJun,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;}
                    else{;}
                }
                else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange>=4){
                printCard($keysJun,$monthJun,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
                else if($page==2&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<6){
                    if($printRange>=4){
                        ;
                    }
                    else{printCard($keysJun,$monthJun,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;}
                }
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysMay)){
                if($page==3){
                    if($printRange<5){printCard($keysMay,$monthMay,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;
                    }
                    else{;}
                }
                else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange>=5){
                printCard($keysMay,$monthMay,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
                else if($page==2&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<6){
                    if($printRange>=5){
                        ;
                    }else{printCard($keysMay,$monthMay,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;}
                }
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysApr)){
                if($pages_needed==4&&$page==3){
                printCard($keysApr,$monthApr,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
                else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange>=6){
                printCard($keysApr,$monthApr,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
                else if($page==2&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<6){
                printCard($keysApr,$monthApr,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysMar)){
                if($page==4){
                    if($printRange<=7){printCard($keysMar,$monthMar,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;}
                    else{;}
                    }
                    else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange>=7){
                    printCard($keysMar,$monthMar,$count);
                    $contentPrint++;}
                    else if($page==2&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<9){
                        if($printRange>=7){
                            ;
                        }
                        else{printCard($keysMar,$monthMar,$count);
                            $contentPrint++;}
                    }
                    else if($page==3&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<9){
                        if($printRange<=7){
                            ;
                        }
                        else{printCard($keysMar,$monthMar,$count);
                            echo "$printRange";
                            $contentPrint++;}
                    }
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysFeb)){
                if($page==4){
                    if($printRange<=8){printCard($keysFeb,$monthFeb,$count);
                        $contentPrint++;}
                    else{;}
                    }
                    else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange>=8){
                    printCard($keysFeb,$monthFeb,$count);
                    $contentPrint++;}
                    else if($page==2&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<9){
                        if($printRange>=8){
                            ;
                        }
                        else{printCard($keysFeb,$monthFeb,$count);
                            $contentPrint++;}
                    }
                    else if($page==3&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<9){
                        if($printRange<=8){
                            ;
                        }
                        else{printCard($keysFeb,$monthFeb,$count);
                            $contentPrint++;}
                    }
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
            if(!empty($keysJan)){
                if($pages_needed==4&&$page==4){
                printCard($keysJan,$monthJan,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
                else if($page==1&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange>=9){
                printCard($keysJan,$monthJan,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
                else if($page==2&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<9){
                printCard($keysJan,$monthJan,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
                else if($page==3&&$contentPrint<3&&$printRange<9){
                printCard($keysJan,$monthJan,$count);
                $contentPrint++;}
            }
            else{
                $printRange++;
            }
```

So I set a condition on how the card should be printed. I'm not sure how can I check whether the carousel is already printed on previous page so I made this lot of conditions.

This is how I store the array

```
foreach($results as $row){
    // while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        $data[] = $row['year_news'];
        $dataMon[] = $row['month_news'];
        
        if($row['month_news']=="December")
        {$monthDec = $row['month_news'];
        $keysDec[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysDec);
        }
        else if($row['month_news']=="November")
        {$monthNov = $row['month_news'];
        $keysNov[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysNov);
        }
        else if($row['month_news']=="October")
        {$monthOct = $row['month_news'];
        $keysOct[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysOct);
        }

        else if($row['month_news']=="September")
        {$monthSep = $row['month_news'];
        $keysSep[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysSep);
        }
        else if($row['month_news']=="August")
        {$monthAug = $row['month_news'];
        $keysAug[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysAug);
        }
        else if($row['month_news']=="July")
        {$monthJul = $row['month_news'];
        $keysJul[] = $row;
        
        }

        else if($row['month_news']=="June")
        {$monthJun = $row['month_news'];
        $keysJun[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysJun);
        }
        else if($row['month_news']=="May")
        {$monthMay = $row['month_news'];
        $keysMay[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysMay);
        }
        else if($row['month_news']=="April")
        {$monthApr = $row['month_news'];
        $keysApr[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysApr);
        }

        else if($row['month_news']=="March")
        {$monthMar = $row['month_news'];
        $keysMar[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysMar);
        }
        else if($row['month_news']=="February")
        {$monthFeb = $row['month_news'];
        $keysFeb[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysFeb);
        }
        else if($row['month_news']=="January")
        {$monthJan = $row['month_news'];
        $keysJan[] = $row;
        array_push($existed, $keysJan);
        }
        // $count2++;
    }
```

Comment: Please try to specify the exact problem.  What dou you want to achive and what is not working.

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig the problem I currently facing is when I inserting the data into the database let say I put data for month January, February, March and June.  So the first page should be display June, March and February. On second page should be January only